# ActionScript 3.0 End Game Countdown Timer

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in actionscript 3.0. I currently have a countdown timer (counts down from 30 seconds). Once the 30 seconds is up I want the frame to move from frame 2 to frame 3. I have put `gotoAndStop(3)` in the code under the timer but when the timer starts it goes to frame 3 straight away. It doesnt go to frame 3 when the 30 seconds is up. I would appreciate any help at all!

```
var nCount:Number = 30;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, nCount);

timer_text.text = nCount.toString(nCount);
myTimer.start();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    nCount--;
    timer_text.text = nCount.toString(); 
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `gotoAndStop(3);` on the very first timer event, i.e. after one second since you are not checking the value of `nCount`. You need to call `gotoAndStop(3);` only when `nCount` is zero.

```
function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void {
    nCount--;
    timer_text.text = nCount.toString(); 
    if (nCount == 0) {
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```